# creating folder in C on windows

Tags: visual-c++

Using Visual Studio 2008 C++, how can I create a folder using code. For some reason, a simple CreateDirectory isn't working.

Comment: Perhaps a snippet of your code would help.

Comment: Why are the tags n titles all mixed up? ur posting in c & askin abt visual c++???

Comment: See also [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Writing in C, but using Visual C++ as the compiler. And I can use either C or C++ code.

Comment: You need to post the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance trying to create a folder in your Visual Studio solution?  If so, you could use code to do that, but you still have to right click the solution and add existing items.

Comment: Hmm, it's a Win32 Console Application (Empty Project---no precompiled header). I add a .cpp file, and write the code there. What include files should I use?

Comment: You need to `#include <Windows.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
CreateDirectory("c:\\dirn.txt");
```

to

```
CreateDirectory("c:\\dirn.txt", null);
```

Comment: In the future, use the formatting tools for code in your answers/questions.  In-line code between the ` character and multi-line code indented by four spaces.